# Different new thread culture behavior in .NET 4.5 and 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Can anyone explain this difference in behavior for different versions of .NET Framework?

```
 // en-US by default
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
var th = new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()));
th.Start();
// .NET 4.5: print US date
// .NET 4.6: print FR date
```

Thank you

Comment: Yes, that's a new 4.6 feature.  CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture() in 4.5 was a less-than-perfect workaround for the age-old problem of culture not flowing from one thread to another.  They did the work in 4.6 to really fix it.  Essential to make async code work trouble-free.  The MSDN article for CultureInfo.CurrentCulture talks about the 4.6 changes, not completely accurately afaict since it is shy of documenting that it also works for the Thread class.